# OpenCV - cv::dnn::Layer::forward equivalent signature in Python

Tags: opencv

What's the Python equivalent to the C++ signature : `cv::dnn::Layer::forward`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/08/21/deep-learning-with-opencv/), it's `net.forward()`:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])
net.setInput(blob)
preds = net.forward()
```

Answer (score 0):

`forward` is a [method](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d6c/classcv_1_1dnn_1_1Layer.html#a73b2805c23c1ed07dea8e6a99d96feaf) name of Layer so it can't be used without class object.

Usage example:

```
mylayer.forward(...)
```